# Checkbox usage in datatables returns wrong array

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, datatables

I'm trying to implement a checkbox inside my datatables. When a row is selected I will store information from this row ( the name ) in an array. Afterwards I can perform a function on this array.

The datatable works with pagination and variabel page length, this is where the problem comes in.

**Case:**

Datatables with length of 10 items per page. I select multiple from the first 10 rows. I change the page length from 10 to 25, select more rows from the new 15 lines and they will appear in the `selectedArray`. But when I uncheck the rows from the first 10 they will be removed from the array and will be repushed in the array. Only the ones that were already checked before I canged the page length will have this behaviour, the others even don't appear.

**Logical example:**

*Array page size 10, x = selected*

`[(x)test1, (x)test2, test3, .., test10]`

```
selectedArray
[test1, test2]
```

*Page size 10 -> 25*

`[(x)test1, (x)test2, test3, .., (x)test11, (x)test12, .., test25]`

```
selectedArray
[test1, test2, test11, test12]
```

*Unselect row from first 10*

`[test1, (x)test2, test3, .., (x)test11, (x)test12, .., test25]`

```
selectedArray
[test2, test11, test12, test1]
```

*Select row from first 10 again*

`[(x)test1, (x)test2, test3, .., (x)test11, (x)test12, .., test25]`

```
selectedArray
[test2, test11, test12, test1]
```

test3 will never appear in the list after changing to page size 25.

**Typescript Component**

```
this.dtOptions = {
 pagingType: 'full_numbers',
 searching: true,
 pageLength: 10,
 processing:true,
 responsive:true,
 order: [[ 1, "asc" ]],
 lengthChange: true,
 lengthMenu: [[10, 15, 20, 25, 50], [10, 15, 20, 50]],
 autoWidth: false,
 stateSave: true,
 stateDuration: 48,
 retrieve: true,
 paging: true,
 columns: [
          { 'data': 'null', defaultContent: ''},
          { 'data': 'name'},
          { 'data': 'version' },
          { 'data': 'newVersion' },
          { 'data': 'null' }
],
columnDefs: [
{
   targets : 0, render:function() {
    return '<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-object-id="">';
   }
 }
],
rowCallback: (row: Node, data: object, index: number) => {
 $('td', row).unbind('click');
 $('td:first input',row).bind('click', () => { // CHECKBOX
  this.selectPackage(data['name'])
  if(this.isSelected(data['name'])){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]', row).prop('checked');
   }
  })
 return row;
 },
ajax: ....
}
```

```
isSelected(name) {
    return this.getIndexFrom(name) >= 0;
}

getIndexFrom(name) {
    return this.selectedPackages.indexOf(name);
}

selectPackage(name) {
 const index = this.selectedPackages.indexOf(name);
  if (index >= 0) {
   this.selectedPackages.splice(index, 1);
 } else {
   this.selectedPackages.push(name);
 }
   this.selectAll = false;
}
```

**row looks like**

```
<tr role="row" class="even">
 <td>
   <input type="checkbox" class="check" data-object-id="">
 </td>
 <td class="sorting_1">
   AA_test
 </td>
 <td></td>
 <td>NaN</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
```

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: `columnDefs` is declared but never read, `rowCallback` is declared but never called - are they relevant, if yes, then how, and if not, then why include them? And why are you using jQuery in a supposedly Angular app?

Comment: `columnDefs` and `rowCallback` are part of dtOptions.  You can find more information about using jQuery and Angular here: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out my implementation of binding was wrong. This is my solution:

```
rowCallback: (row: Node, data: object, index: number) => {
          const checkbox =  $('td:first input',row);
          checkbox.prop('checked', this.isSelected(data['name']));
          checkbox.unbind();
          checkbox.click(() => this.selectPackage(data['name']));
          return row
}
```